# Redirect to a page when the reponse is not error

Tags: ajax, jquery, redirect

I have a form where i provide a name and submit . This uses ajax and i get respose from the server . IF I dont add a name and try to submit i get an error message . 
I want to redirect to a url when the submit was successful and not redirect when response was error .

below is the screenshot of firebug which shows successful and error respose
[response http://i.minus.com/jbaILwvIGfmgX7.bmp](http://i.minus.com/jbaILwvIGfmgX7.bmp)
Please can someone provide a jquery script which can handle such situation .
Do let me know if you need more info from me.
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: what have you tried? (because this is really easy, but i wont help you unless you show that you have at least tried)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+redirect+page

Comment: I have written a script this is for JIRA so we use AJS.$ instead of $ 
<script type="text/Javascript">
AJS.$(function(){
          AJS.$('a').each(function(){
                if(AJS.$(this).html() =='Merge'){
AJS.$(document.body).on('submit', 'form', function(){
var pkey=document.getElementById("project-config-details-project-key").innerHTML;
var burl=AJS.$("input[title='baseURL']").val()
$.ajax({
   success: function() {window.location.href=burl+"/browse/"+pkey+"#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversions-panel";
 }, 
        error: function() { alert("error"); }
});}});

Comment: Why exactly would you submit a form with ajax only to redirect once it's successful. Implement validation and do a regular form submit, and you have pretty much what you're looking for ?

Comment: plz edit that code formatted in your post. do i see this right: the success function always gets called, even if you get the error response from the ajax (that means your json object contains "errorMessages" and "errors"

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax call to this, i think thats what you want

```
$.ajax({ 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(obj.errorMessages == undefined)
        {
            window.location.href=burl+"/browse/"+pkey+"#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plug‌​in.system.project%3Aversions-panel"; 
        }
        else
        {
            alert("error");
        }
    }, 
    error: function() { 
        alert("error"); 
    } 
});
```

the "error" function is for errors happening with the ajax call. but your ajax call is always successful because you always get a valid response. therefor you got to check the returned json for errors

Comment: I tried the script you provided but its not working :( ... Its ok if i dont give an alert on error , I just need to redirect if the response was not error .

Comment: what happens when you get an error? is the success function called? what about my code is not working? what javascript error do you get?

Comment: No the success function is not called , I tested this by adding an alert in the success function .

Comment: so neither your success nor error function is called? that may be because your request returns the 400 Bad Request Status (as i see from your screenshot). that is a problem with your server or with the url you are calling. what url are you calling anyway? i didnt see you setting it anywhere. you need to define $.ajax({url: "your request url", ... somehow

Comment: This is my first script using AJAX , m a complete newbie , from firebug i found when i click request is sent to http://localhost:8081/rest/api/2/version . Please can you help me from scratch ?

Comment: well, to help you, i would have to know what you are trying to do. what script are you trying to call with ajax? if you call it manually (by typing the request url in the browser url bar), does it work like you want it?

Comment: We use JIRA (project tracking tool) here we create versions .. I want to redirect the user to a page where the user will enter more details of the version , But redirection should happen only if version is created . So I need a script which i will apply in the announcement banner (present on all pages) .
The url is created dynamically i guess , if you see the response of successful version creation in the screenshot you will see the url .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22969/discussion-between-mizan-and-x4rf41)